# Zsh / Shell - how to assign something to a variable quietly?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, zsh, ksh

I'm having trouble assigning a value quietly ( no console output ) to a variable.

I want to assign `npm list -g`to a variable but without any console output, so I did this:

```
npm_list=$(npm list -g &> /dev/null)
```

but when I do that `$npm_list` outputs nothing ( I think because I return npm's output to /dev/null ).

yeah..., so how do I do it? I'm pretty new to shell programming.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `npm_list=$(npm list -g 2> /dev/null)`. This will only send stderr output to `/dev/null`, allowing the main output to be captured into a variable. Good luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Git bash shell (sorry, I'm on Windows right now, so no Zsh available), this works for me

```
npm_list=$(npm list -g 2> /dev/null)
```

Comment: alot of "npm WARN package.json.." warnings :/

Comment: Use `2>` instead of `&>` to direct just errors to `/dev/null`.  I just updated my answer.

Comment: thanks alot!
one more off-topic question maybe: do you know any good (zsh) shell books/resources?

Comment: Yes, there's a book "From Bash to Zsh". I like it since it includes some things about `bash` too, which is useful because we still live in a predominately `bash` world, and I use `bash` on machines that don't have `zsh` installed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are sending all of the output from the command to `/dev/null` so the `$()` doesn't capture the output properly.

What you want is simply:

```
npm_list=$(npm list 2>/dev/null)
```

Though you probably want something that you can process, which would be:

```
npm_list=$(npm list --parseable 2>/dev/null | tail -n +2)
```

Answer (score 3):

`npm_list=$(npm list -g) &> /dev/null`

this seems to do the trick :)

still I have no idea what the ampersand in `&>` exactly means.

when I echo `$npm_list` now tho, it has all the npm packages in it.

Comment: The ampersand instructs the shell to redirect both standard output and standard error. `$(...)` captures only the standard output, leaving the standard error to be redirected to `/dev/null`.